# sample Soap Message that calls a SavedSearch by the ID

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

I was wondering if someone has an example using **SuiteTalk**, i was searching but could not find any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a SOAP request that executes a customer search with the internal ID of the search.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <tokenPassport xmlns="urn:messages_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <account xmlns="urn:core_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">**********</account>
            <consumerKey xmlns="urn:core_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****************************************************************</consumerKey>
            <token xmlns="urn:core_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">****************************************************************</token>
            <nonce xmlns="urn:core_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">b591c9bfb56c406c9cf79252783dac7f</nonce>
            <timestamp xmlns="urn:core_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">1605312585</timestamp>
            <signature algorithm="HMAC_SHA256" xmlns="urn:core_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">********************************************</signature>
        </tokenPassport>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <search xmlns="urn:messages_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <searchRecord savedSearchId="366" xsi:type="q1:CustomerSearchAdvanced" xmlns:q1="urn:relationships_2019_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
        </search>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It looks like this with C#

```
var search = new CustomerSearchAdvanced()
{
    savedSearchId = "366"
};

var results = ns.search(search);
```